# Example in database/sql using sql.ErrNoRows crashes and burns

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a small Go program which uses a a postgresql db. In it there is a query which can return no rows, and the code I'm using to deal with this isn't working correctly.

```
    // Get the karma value for nick from the database.
func getKarma(nick string, db *sql.DB) string {
    var karma int
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT SUM(delta) FROM karma WHERE nick = $1", nick).Scan(&karma)
    var karmaStr string
    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        karmaStr = fmt.Sprintf("%s has no karma.", nick)
    case err != nil:
        log.Fatal(err)
    default:
       karmaStr = fmt.Sprintf("Karma for %s is %d.", nick, karma)
    }
    return karmaStr
}
```

This logic is taken directly from the [Go documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query). When there are no rows corresponding to **nick**, the following error occurs:

```
2016/07/24 19:37:07 sql: Scan error on column index 0: converting driver.Value type <nil> ("<nil>") to a int: invalid syntax
```

I must be doing something stupid - clues appreciated.

Comment: If you're always comparing to `err` in your switch, why not use `switch err{}` instead?

Comment: Which "database/sql" documentation are you referring to? That code is most definitely not in the Postgres manual

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query, expand the example for QueryRow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you're getting a `NULL` value back from the database, which go translates into `nil`. However, you're scanning into an integer, which has no concept of `nil`. One thing you can do is scan into a type that implements the [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface (and can handle `NULL` values), e.g., [`sql.NullInt64`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64).

In the example code in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow), I'd assume they have a `NOT NULL` constraint on the `username` column. I think the reason for this is because they didn't want to lead people to believe that you *have* to use NULL-able types across the board.

Answer (score 1):

I reworked the code to get the results I wanted.

```
// Get the karma value for nick from the database.
func getKarma(nick string, db *sql.DB) string {
    var karma int
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT SUM(delta) FROM karma WHERE nick = $1", nick)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    karmaStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s has no karma.", nick)
    if rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&karma)
        karmaStr = fmt.Sprintf("Karma for %s is %d.", nick, karma)
    }
    return karmaStr
}
```

Tempted to submit a documentation patch of some sort to the database/sql package.

Comment: Documentation patch seems like the right path. If they want their code to work, they should really use an example query that can return 0 or 1 rows, like 'select id from user where email=$1' (assuming a unique index on email). Aggregates always returning a row (even a row containing nulls) threw them off.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized the code in the question is a variation of the doc sample with a different query, not the exact code. The documentation is right as Spencer Judd said--the problem is in the subtle difference between a non-aggregate query that looks at no rows (and returns nothing) vs. an aggregate one (that returns NULL).